# z3py: How to convert a formula into NNF format?

Tags: smt, z3py, negation

I wanted to convert a formula to its NNF format using z3py. For e.g.,

Given

```
Or(Not(And(i1, Not(And(i0, i4, i1, i2)))), And(i3, i1, i2))
```

I want

```
Or(Not(i1), And(i0, i4, i1, i2), And(i3, i1, i2))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `nnf` tactic, followed by `simplify`:

```py
from z3 import *

i0, i1, i2, i3, i4 = Bools("i0 i1 i2 i3 i4")
g = Goal()
g.add(Or(Not(And(i1, Not(And(i0, i4, i1, i2)))), And(i3, i1, i2)))
print(g)
t = Then(Tactic('nnf'), Tactic('simplify'))
print(t(g))
```

This prints:

```
[Or(Not(And(i1, Not(And(i0, i4, i1, i2)))), And(i3, i1, i2))]
[[Or(And(i0, i4, i1, i2), And(i3, i1, i2), Not(i1))]]
```

the result is a list of goals; but a singleton goal is the same as your formula. (A goal can split a formula into many parts, and hence the list output.)